# Issue passing an id using router-go package

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-go-router, flutter-routes

I'm trying to route to specific id /product/:id but when i click on my card to navigate it shows an error , but when i do hot reload it works.

**Here is the error
**> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

go-router in main.dart

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const MainPage();
      },
    ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/product/:id',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state)=>  DetailsView(id:state.params["id"]!)
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/homepage',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const HomePage();
        },
      ),
  ],
);
```

here is how i route to my product/:id (I'm using Carousel Slider).

```
Widget buildImage(String urlImage, String title, int price, double padding,
        int index, String id, BuildContext context) =>
    GestureDetector(
      **onTap: () {
        context.push("/product/$id");
      },**
      child: Container(
............))) etc
```

and here is my detailsView page which when navigating to the error appears.

```
class DetailsView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  /// Constructs a [DetailsScreen]
  const DetailsView({super.key, required this.id});
  @override
  State<DetailsView> createState() => _DetailsViewState();
}

class _DetailsViewState extends State<DetailsView> {
  var urlImage;
  var description;
  var price;
  var title;
  getProductInfo(id) async {
    devtools.log(id);
    var productRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('products')
        .doc(id)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
              urlImage = doc.get("urlImage"),
              description = doc.get("description"),
              price = doc.get("price"),
              title = doc.get("title"),
            });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    var id = widget.id;
    getProductInfo(id);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

.....}
```

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' , this error appears when i navigate to my page using go-router package

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `id` is `null`. Make sure your `id` is not null before passing it as `id` in the router by `debugPrint`.

```
      onTap: () {
       debugPrint("The value of id is $id"); // Here you should get some string instead of null
       if(id !=null) {context.push("/product/$id");}
      },
```

---

**Edit**: Try using named route (**Guaranteed to work**)

```
 GoRoute(
    path: '/product/:id',  
    name: 'product',
    builder: (context, state) => DetailsView(
      id: state.params['id']
    ),
  ),
```

And use:

```
 onTap: () {
   context.pushNamed("product", params: {'id1': id});
 },
```

Comment: it is printing a string , i added this h but didn't work,
                                                                                                                               
_════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building DetailsView(dirty, state: _DetailsViewState#0bd2f):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The relevant error-causing widget was
DetailsView
main.dart:54
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _DetailsViewState.build_

Comment: It is because `id` is null

Comment: but it is printing my id , here is a snippet https://snipboard.io/VuT7Fs.jpg

Comment: Please check out my updated code, try passing it in the params section, as in the `edit` part of my code.

Comment: the same error occurs, the problem is in detailsView.dart file

Comment: Can you print id value in the detailsView, and point me exactly where the error is shown , in the question

Comment: https://snipboard.io/iebflP.jpg yes it it printing my id,https://github.com/Y7gn/Flutter_resturant_project1.git btw here is my repository

Comment: In the debug console , in which line does this occur point me the line in the detailsScreen which is causing this error.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/mI06TO.jpg

Comment: change `state.params['id]` to `state.params['id']!`

Comment: https://snipboard.io/dukeIZ.jpg , red thing removed but still error

Comment: Send me the 55th line of `DetailsView`

Comment: it's just a button , no problems , the error was in 55th line of main.dart , and once i click on it , it navigates to where i showed in my last image